# Convert raw data to jpeg

Tags: java, android

I have found a way on how to convert raw data to jpeg but I have some issues with it.
My app takes a picture on the current frame (onPreviewFrame) and has the raw data in a bytearray.

First of all, the code I found is only supported by android API 7+ (Android 2.1+). I want this app to be able to use since API 4+  so android 1.6 users can also enjoy the app.
Second thing is that I have found some code to convert raw2jpg, but it is copyright protected so I can't use it.

I want to put it in a bytearray, so I won't use takePicture with it, remember.

Does anyone have an idea or some code snippet that I can use on how to *convert* **raw data** taken on a current frame **to** make a **jpeg image** in a bytearray from Android version 1.6?

EDIT: Here is the code:

```
private void raw2jpg(int[] rgb, byte[] raw, int width, int height)
{
            final int frameSize = width * height;

            for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
            int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++)
            {
                    int y=0;
                    if( yp < raw.length)
                    {
                            y = (0xff & ((int) raw[yp])) - 16;
                    }
//                      int y = (0xff & ((int) raw[yp])) - 16;
                    if (y < 0) y = 0;
                    if ((i & 1) == 0)
                    {
                            if(uvp<raw.length)
                            {
                                    v = (0xff & raw[uvp++]) - 128;
                                    u = (0xff & raw[uvp++]) - 128;
                            }
                    }

                    int y1192 = 1192 * y;
                    int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
                    int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
                    int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

                    if (r < 0) r = 0; else if (r > 262143) r = 262143;
                    if (g < 0) g = 0; else if (g > 262143) g = 262143;
                    if (b < 0) b = 0; else if (b > 262143) b = 262143;

                    rgb[yp] =       0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 
                                            0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) &
                                                    0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 
                                                    0xff);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and go for api 7. Only 3.6% use anything below that and it will be even less soon.

Comment: Ok, Posted the code, I will go for api 7 then. But still I cannot use the code as it is licensed under GNU GPL 2. This means I can use the code if the app is open source.