# Convert raw RGB32 file to JPEG or PNG using FFmpeg

Tags: c++, command-line, ffmpeg, png, jpeg

**Context**

I used a `C++` program to write raw bytes to a file (image.raw) in `RGB32` format:

`R G B A R G B A R G B A ...`

and I want to be able to view it in some way. I have the dimensions of the image.

My tools are limited to command line commands (e.g. `ffmpeg`). I have visited the `ffmpeg` [website](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) for instructions, but it deals more with converting videos to images.

---

**Questions**

Is it possible to turn this file into a viewable file type (e.g. `.jpeg`, `.png`) using `ffmpeg`. If so, how would I do it?

If it's not possible, is there a way I can use another command?

It that's still not viable, is there any way I can manipulate the `RGB32` bytes inside a C++ program to make it more suitable **without** the use of external libraries? I also don't want to encode `.jpeg` myself like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723932/convert-raw-data-to-jpeg).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [rawvideo demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#rawvideo):

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pixel_format rgba -video_size 320x240 -i input.raw output.png
```

Since there is no header specifying the assumed video parameters you must specify them, as shown above, in order to be able to decode the data correctly.

See `ffmpeg -pix_fmts` for a list of supported input pixel formats which may help you choose the appropriate `-pixel_format`.

Comment: Answer worked for me, although I have to add it only worked after I added `-i` before `input.raw`.

Comment: @PhotometricStereo Yes, that was a typo. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: For jpg, try `ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgba -s 320x240 -i input.raw -vcodec mjpeg -pix_fmt yuvj420p output.jpg`

Comment: In case it helps someone, you can replace `-i input.raw` with `-i -` so you can simply pipe the output of a program into ffmpeg without having to store the intermediate result (the raw data) in a file.

Comment: Going in the other direction: ffmpeg -i inputfilename -s wxh outputfilename.rgb produces file with 3 bytes per pixel r followed by g and b (at least on x86 machines).

Answer (score 0):

get a single frame from raw RGBA data

```
ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgba -ss 00:01 -r 1 -s 320x240 -i input.raw -frames:v 1 output.png
```

`-y` overwrite output
`-r` input framerate (placed before `-i`)
`-ss` skip to this time
`-frames:v` number of frames ot output